# findComponent in iframe

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, ajax

I have a page with an iframe like this:

```
<iframe runat="server" id="rsPrintFrame" src="framedPage.aspx" height="0" width="0"></iframe>
```

I need to get access to a component on the 'framed' page from the parent page, as one would typically do with `$find()` or `Sys.Application.findComponent()`.  But obviously I can't simply do:  `myFrame.contentWindow.document.$find()`.

I've come up with a work-around involving making the `$find()` call in the framed page and saving it to a variable accessible to the parent page via javascript.

But is there a straightforward way to call `findComponent()` from the parent page while targeting a framed page's element/component.

BTW, `getElementById()` is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: If the iframe is named, shouldn't you be able to access if via getElementsByName()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot use the $find from the parent window to find a component in the child window. You can do this however:

```
var component = myFrame.contentWindow.$find("myComponentId");
```

If you are using this often you can create a wrapper function.

Comment: How could that possibly work?  $find() is just a shortcut for Sys.Application.findComponent()..  So I don't think myFrame.contentWindow.Sys.Application.findComponent() is valid.

Comment: If ASP.NET Ajax is loaded in that frame (I assume it is because otherwise the component wouldn't have worked) this should be no problem. Have in mind that $find is the same as window.$find which is the same as window.Sys.Application.findComponent. When dealing with frames (and iframes for that matter) contentWindow is the window of the frame. I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, slap me around and call me Susan... you're right, this worked:  myFrame.contentWindow.$find(id)

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
window.frames['<%= rsPrintFrame.ClientID %>'].document....
```

Comment: Nope, nothing to do with server-side scripting.